# How to calculate a single Abrikosov vortex's structure in superconductor through Ginzberg-Landau theory when $\kappa$ near $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, vortex

As the title. We can find the approximate solution for large $\kappa$ in any textbook about superconductor.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "structure"? Do you mean superfluid density profile? Also, would be helpful to give a more precise reference. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the unclearness. "Structure" means the distributions of the order parameter $\psi$ and the vector potential, which describing the magnetic field.